# How to compile source code with makefile having debug info?

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, makefile, compilation

I have the source code of glibc and I want to debug it using gdb.from what I know is I need to run makefile of glibc to compile it. So how can I add debug flag in the makefile of it so it can be debugged?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: I am using ubuntu

Comment: Since you already have the debug version of glibc installed (it's the `libc6-dbg` package), all you really need to do is download the libc6 source from Ubuntu and give gdb a command to show which directory the source is in. This is much easier and less risky than building and using the generic glibc without all the Ubuntu customizations. Would you like to do this?

Comment: Thanks,I  got it but I want to debug other's source code also.so I want to know the procedure.

Comment: `CXXFLAGS += -g` If that does not make sense to you, then you must learn the basics of makefiles before you ask a question like this.